# Java Json "the import org cannot be resolved"

Tags: java, json, eclipse, org.json

JRE-9.0.4 
IDE-Eclipse Photon

I have included the java-json.jar file in my build but for some reason, it's still not allowing me to reference the classes. I have made projects before using the base JRE classes and never had to import jars before so sorry if it is a very obvious mistake.

-I have tried restarting Eclipse to no avail.
-Looked at several answers on overflow to no avail.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBxyN.png)

[Screenshot of the libraries window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ni7iO.png)

[Screenshot with new .jar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qsMd.png)

Comment: Can you describe the steps you followed in order to import the Jar?

Comment: I downloaded the .zip folder, unzipped it to get the jar. Went to the libraries window  and added the .jar to the classpath. Here is a link to the zip where I got it from https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java

Comment: Just second click on the Project name, build path and then add external JAR. Select your file and viola

Comment: that's exactly how I got to the libraries window sorry for not explaining that still not it.

Comment: Could you try with this jar? [Json](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/json/json/20160810/json-20160810.jar)

Comment: Unfortunately still nothing. Added a third screenshot with the new .jar

Comment: Wonder why are you using JAva 9?

Comment: Because its the latest java as far as I know from when I last checked

Answer (score 1):

I figured out why.

According to the docs:

> The package compiles on Java 1.6-1.8.

So, you probably want to switch to **JDK** 8, which is LTS (long term support) version.

you can get it from:  [Java SE Development Kit 8u191](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

[image: steps]

---

Now, if you want a library to manipulate JSON, you could could use:

> Homepage: https://github.com/google/gson
>
> Tutorial: [Java Google Json (Gson) Introduction](http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-google-json-introduction/)
>
> Download: [Google gson](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.5/gson-2.8.5.jar)

---

> Homepage: [json-simple](https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/)
>
> Tutorial: [JSON.Simple Example to read and write JSON in Java](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/json/json-simple/json-simple-example-to-read-and-write-json-in-java/)
>
> Download: [json-simple-1.1.1.jar](http://json-simple.googlecode.com/files/json-simple-1.1.1.jar)